# "Internal hard drive not found" error displayed while trying to boot laptop

Tags: hard-drive, boot

> Internal hard disk drive not found. To resolve this issue, try to reseat the drive. No bootable devices--strike F1 to retry boot, F2 enter Setup Menu, F5 enter PSA.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you made any hardware changes?

Comment: No, it's a laptop that I've never even opened yet.

Comment: Yes, that is odd. Does it continue to give this same message if you hit F1?

Answer (score 0):

This message means that the internal drive is not found.

- Either the drive broke,
- or the connector between drive and the motherboard broke (or came loose)
- or something on the motherboard broke.

To check if the drive is broken, remove the drive and try to use it with another computer. E.g.. plug in in as an extra drive in a desktop, use an external USB case or use a HDD dock like these:

[image: HDD dock]

To try to solve the middle problem, remove the drive from the laptop and reconnect it. This is called 'reseating the drive`.

If the drive works fine in a dock or in another computer then it is likely a problem with the laptop. Try using another drive and see if it also fails (it probably will give the same problem) so you can confirm this. If it is then check if the laptop is still under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used the machine before, and it is causing this kind of problem, you should return it to the seller.